# Bitlocker Encryption on All Drives

Tags: powershell, batch-file, bitlocker

I have a script for bitlocker encryption that encrypts system drive. now my management wants to include all other data drives.

Now, I'm having a hard time creating a for loop because drives is not displaying. so assigned variables are not able to run properly on commands a throw.

I wanted to do a for loop to check all data drives except external drives and usb using

```
wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get deviceid /format:list
```

but I'm quite having a hard time. I have put my modified script that is not working yet below.

If you think what I have is a spaghetti code, please help me modify. maybe you have other efficient way.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=:" %%L in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get deviceid /format:list') do (
    echo Checking drive: %%L
    for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('manage-bde -status %%L ^| findstr "    Encryption Method:"') do (
        if "%%A"=="AES" goto EncryptionCompleted
    )
    for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('manage-bde -status %%L ^| findstr "    Encryption Method:"') do (
        if "%%A"=="XTS-AES" goto EncryptionCompleted
    )
    for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('manage-bde -status %%L ^| findstr "    Encryption Method:"') do (
        if "%%A"=="None" goto TPMActivate
    )
    goto ElevateAccess
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try it something more like this:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKU\S-1-5-19" >NUL 2>&1 || (
    Echo This must be Run as administrator.
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
    Exit /B)

For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 LogicalDisk Where "DriveType = 3" Get DeviceID /Format:MOF 2^>NUL'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\manage-bde.exe -Status %%G
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Encryption Method:" 2^>NUL'
) Do If "%%H" == "None" (GoTo TPMActivate
) Else If Not "%%H" == "AES" If Not "%%H" == "XTS-AES" GoTo ElevateAccess

:EncryptionCompleted
```

Please note: This is simply a fix for your submitted code with improvements. It does not however do what I think you intended of it. Once it has parsed the first `Fixed Disk` it will `GoTo` another label and exit the loop. It will not therefore action against another disk, so if that was you intention, you'd need to perform more work yourself.

Comment: BTW, as a tip for performing the rest yourself, you need to look into the use of the `Call` command.